# How do you get just the parent element of a click event when event.target is returning the children?

Tags: javascript, html, events

JavaScript

```
function productBox(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    console.log(event.target);
}
var product = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
for (var g = 0, length = product.length; g < length; g++){
    console.log('here');
    product[g].addEventListener('click',productBox);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="product">
    <div class="productContent">
       <img src="file:///C|/Users/Jacob/Downloads/12939681_1597112303636437_733183642_n.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="productName">
         Here
    </div>
    <div class="productDescription">

    </div>
```

So the problem lies in the fact that when the product element is clicked, event.target returns the actual child element of the event listener. For example, i click a "product" and it'll return productContent, productName or productDescription as the target, when actually what i want is the "product" element and then to do a .childNodes and find the image within that.

Please note jQuery is not an option, it is 30kb of stuff i won't use as this is a static html page with barely any javascript.

I've thought perhaps,

doing a check if the element is 'product' if not, take the parent and check if it's a 'product', if not go to that parent and so on. Then find the img tag within that. But i feel like that is a long winded work around.

Any thoughts?

Comment: This or currentTarget don't work? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget

Comment: `this` gives you the bound element.

Comment: Thank you. `this`  works. Completely forgot that `this` is where it's called not defined. Want to put as an answer so i can accept?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the element to which the handler is bound, you can use `this` within the handler.

As [@DaveNewton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438992/dave-newton) pointed out, the `event` object has a [`.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) property that can be used as well. This is nice because you can have functions that have a manually bound `this` using `.bind()` or you may be using the [new arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which have a `this` defined by its original environment, making it impossible to get the bound element that way.

Answer (score 3):

You can use parentElement property of the target.

```
function productBox(event){
    var target = event.target;
    var parent = target.parentElement;//parent of "target"
    //Rest of your code
}
```

Comment: I tried that. Issue is if the event fires on the image (or any other children-child elements) meaning parentElement will return "productContent". Or in event that the event.target actually returns "product" then it'll get the element above it.

Comment: That seems long-winded, and not general purpose since there may be additional nested dom elements.

Comment: In that case, you should use 'this' within your handler.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question: if you have a `element.click(function(){})` and the element has two or multiple siblings. If the event trigger is attached to the parent and not the target, this post popped up and is actually irrelevant to my question so I decided to post my search here for someone else.

I used this method:

```
if (target.closest('.NEftune').attr('rel') != undefined){
 /*do something here*/ 
}
```

The closest method in jQuery and JavaScript starts from the clicked target and then bubbles up until it finds an attribute you looking for. In my case the event was attached to an Element with the class (.NEftune) and by adding an extra attribute I could determine if I was inside the container (.NEftune) which has an image inside.

Comment: What is “NEftune”? The question is about “product”. It’s also about `console.log(event.target)`, not about some `rel` attribute. Please make sure you actually answer the question.

Comment: Sebastian i think you read the question wrong. They trying to click the parent not the siblings, .NEftune is the parent of the clicked element, if you feel better doing so, substitute .NEftune with .product || #product. why the extra attribute? in this case rel, is to ensure the bubble up runs its full course at the first .NEftune it finds.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but the simplest solution to get the actual target to which the event handler was attached to is to use the event `currentTarget` property.

This will avoid unnecessary further DOM check and works out of the box on all modern browsers.

[Event.currentTarget on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

> The currentTarget read-only property of the Event interface identifies the current target for the event, as the event traverses the DOM. It always refers to the element to which the event handler has been attached, as opposed to Event.target, which identifies the element on which the event occurred and which may be its descendant.